# How to count HTML tags in C++?

Tags: html, c++, parsing

I am new to learning C++ and for a class I am tasked with an assignment to create a parser for HTML files in C++. The program is to input a file name, and output that file's contents, how many lines, character, tags, links, comments, and what percent of characters are in tags.

I have most of the program complete, I am just stumbling on one part: how to count the number of tags in the HTML file. Below is what I have so far. My issue in particular is with lines 106-109, the part that starts with "if(fileChar == TAG)"

Other questions related to this topic either aren't answered, or are using libraries I am not allowed to.

Since this is for a class ideally I am looking for a method that does not involve libraries other than the ones listed in the header files. Any help would be much appreciated as I am currently banging my head against a wall :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
        const char TAG = '<', //marks the beginning of a tag
        LINK = 'a',     //marks the beginning of a link
        COMMENT = '!';  //marks the beginning of a comment

        char fileChar;  //individual characters from the file
        int charNum=0, //total characters in the file
        tagNum=0,       //total tags in the file
        linkNum=0,      //total links in the file
        commentNum=0,   //total comments in the file
        tagChars=0, //number of chars in tags
        lineNum=0, //number of lines in file
        charPercent=0; //percent of chars in tags


        int count = 0; //for counting

        string fileName; //name of file

        ifstream inFile;

//take in user input

cout << "========================================" << endl;
cout << "   Welcome to the HTML File Analyzer!" << endl;
cout << "========================================" << endl << endl;

  cout << "Please enter a valid file name (with no spaces): " << endl;
  cin >> fileName;

  inFile.open(fileName.c_str());         //opens the file

if(inFile)                //tests if file is open
 cout << "file IS open" << endl;
else
 cout << "file NOT open" << endl;

  while (!inFile) //error checking to ensure file exists
{
    inFile.clear(); //clear false file
    cout << endl << "Re-enter a valid filename: " << endl;
    cin >> fileName;
    inFile.open (fileName.c_str());
}

//display contents of file

cout << "========================================" << endl;
cout << "         Contents of the File           " << endl;
cout << "========================================" << endl << endl;

std:string line;

while(inFile)   //print out contents of the file
{
        getline(inFile, line);
        cout << line <<  endl;
        lineNum++; //add to line counter

        const int size=line.length();
        charNum = charNum + size;
        cout << "The total number of characters entered is: " << charNum << endl;

}

inFile.open(fileName.c_str()); //reopen file

while(inFile)
{
        if (fileChar == TAG)
        {
        tagNum++;
        }

}

cout << "========================================" << endl;
cout << "        End of Contents of File         " << endl;
cout << "========================================" << endl << endl;

inFile.open(fileName.c_str());

while(inFile) //count chars
{
         charNum = charNum + 1;
}
cout << "========================================" << endl;
cout << "            Content Analysis            " << endl;
cout << "========================================" << endl << endl;

cout << "Number of Lines: " << lineNum << endl;
cout << "Number of Tags: " << tagNum << endl;
cout << "Number of Comments: " << commentNum << endl;
cout << "Number of Links: " << linkNum << endl;
cout << "Number of Chars in File: " << charNum << endl;
cout << "Number of Chars in Tags: " << tagChars << endl;
cout << "Percent of Chars in Tags: " << charPercent << endl;
inFile.close ();

return (0);

}
```

Comment: Note You cannot open a file stream if it's already open. The stream is placed in fail state if you try. In this case You can leave the file open, `clear` the EOF flag and seek back to the beginning.

Comment: Also, don't write the whole program all at once. Write a bit, compile and test and then move on to the next bit. If you write it all at once not only have you probably repeated some mistakes, but bugs gang up on you. It is a lot harder to find and fix two bugs than it is to fix one bug and then another bug a few minutes later.

Comment: Can you please be more precise about what subset of HTML you are supposed to parse? Do you have to support comments inside tags? (`<a <!-- ignore me --> >`) Do you have to support arbitrary whitespace in tags? (`< a   href = "some text"    >`) Do you have to support omitted closing tags (`<a><b>foo</a>`) or immediately-closed tags? (`<hr />`)

Comment: Either way, the answer will involve a state machine (in a tag, in a comment, in an attribute name (with its own substates), inside a tag, top-level outside of any tags) and transitions between them based on the input characters. I believe I told you this in a previous question that you deleted.

Comment: Of course if *all* you're supposed to do is count the number of open tags, you simply need to read until you see a `<`, then check if the next character is not a `!` (comment) or a `/` (closing tag). You've already demonstrated that you know how to read characters from a file, so what is the actual problem then?

Comment: Finally: please stop deleting your questions.You have been posting this question (and variations on it) for at least a week now. By asking people (what seems to be) a brand new question every time you waste freely-given time by making them ask the same clarifications over and over again. If a question gets closed, learn why and either improve the question (so it can be reopened) or ask a new question **referencing the old question**.

Comment: @Botje Yes, apologies for the vagueness, all I need to do is count the number of open tags. The issue I have is how to identify the tag when reading the file, not reading the file itself. Also, apologies for deleting the posts. I did not know the proper etiquette if I had a question fairly similar to the one I had asked in the past. I had assumed that answers would just be people directing me to my previous post. I never intended to waste anyone's time, especially someone trying to help.

Comment: Okay, what about tags inside comments, do you have to count those too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that you are dealing with [valid HTML5](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/syntax.html), we can distinguish five cases when you see a `<` character outside of a comment:

- either it is the start of a comment and is followed by `!--`, or
- either it is the start of a DOCTYPE and is followed by `!DOCTYPE`, or
- either it is the start of a CDATA and is followed by `![CDATA[`, or
- it is an end tag and is followed by `/`, or
- it is a start tag and is followed by a tag name.

```
while (inFile) {
  inFile >> fileChar;
  if (inFile != TAG) continue; // We are only interested in potential tag or comment starts.

  inFile >> fileChar;
  if (fileChar == '!') {
    char after1, after2;
    inFile >> after1 >> after2;
    if (after1 == '-' && after2 == '-') {
       // This is the start of a comment.
       // We start eating chars until we see '-->' pass by.
       std::string history = "  ";
       while (inFile) {
         inFile >> fileChar;
         if (history == "--" && fileChar == '>') {
            // end of comment, stop this inner loop.
            commentNum++;
            break;
         }

         // Shift history and copy current character to recent history
         history[0] = history[1];
         history[1] = fileChar;
       }
    }
  } else if (fileChar == '/') {
     // This is a closing tag. Do nothing.
  } else {
     // This is the start of a tag. Read until the first non-letter, non-digit.
     std::string tagName;
     while (inFile) {
       inFile >> fileChar;
       if (std::isalnum(fileChar)) {
         tagName.append(1, fileChar);
       } else {
         tagNum++;
         if (tagName == "a") linkNum++;
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Note that this is a very naïve implementation that only implements a part of the specification. It will probably break if you feed it malformed HTML. It definitely does not handle CDATA blocks (which will treat its contents as HTML instead of unparsed character data). I am not sure what you mean by "percent chars in tags", but that might be something you can track in the last `else` branch.

Finally, note that I wrote it as a single block. You are of course encouraged to factor it into smaller functions (`read_comment` or `read_tag_name`, for example) to increase legibility.

Comment: This solution should be perfect. Many thanks to you for taking time out of your day to help. You are invited to my wedding